# How to read Firefox/Chrome Tabs from a native mac app (without extension)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I would like to know if it is possible to read Firefox/Chrome (and their contents) tabs without installing an extension/add-on from a native app (let's say swift app) on mac OS?

Closely related to this question is if it possible to send a command to firefox/chrome without an extension?

Comment: AFAIK yes, via [Accessibility interface](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility).

Comment: would you care to elaborate a bit @wOxxOm?

Comment: Here's what I know: your app posts a special message to Chrome's process, which puts it into a special mode, then your app can communicate with Chrome and should be able to get the list of tabs and even the contents of the active page. Read the documentation I've linked.

Comment: Googling for "chrome accessibility get list of open tabs" reveals something: [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](//stackoverflow.com/a/40638519) and [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](//stackoverflow.com/a/18983677)